# put JavaScript setTimeout with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a Javascript novice and I'm trying to get a checker that tests email and password, but I need to put `setTimeout` in my code:

This Code is responsible for accessing the api and making a request the same bringing what was defined the code itself works correctly more accurate to put this range I saw some examples but they use settimeout

Below is what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--get out, you will not copy my html-->
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/vendor/animate.css/animate.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/pe-icons/pe-icon-7-stroke.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/pe-icons/helper.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/stroke-icons/style.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://webapplayers.com/luna_admin-v1.1/styles/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
  <!--my own css-->
  <style>
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;

  }
  #top-bar{
      background-color: #3E3D3D;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    
    background-color: #;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
  }
  #title-top-bar{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    left: 55px;
  }
  #logo-top-bar{
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
  }
  #shop-redirect-mold{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #202a38;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
  }
  #shop-redirect-mold2{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -195px;
  }
  #db-list-box{
    background-color: #212a36;
    width: 70%;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
  }
  #lista{
    background-color:#2e;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #686868;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
#botao{
    background-color:#2e;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #686868;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
  #db-list-title{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #db-list-result-cont{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #result-box{
    position: relative;
    left: 205px;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: #212a36;
    width: 800px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }
  #lives{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #28a745;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #dies{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #dc3545;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #socks{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1a222e;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffc107;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
  }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #1a222e;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
}
 </style>
    <!--website content-->
    <body class="animated bounce">
      <!--top bar and navegation-->


     <!--first text box-->
     


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-S7YMK1xjUjSpEnF4P8hPUcgjXYLZKK3fQW1j5ObLSl787II9p8RO9XUGehRmKsxd" crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
 

</head>
<body>

            
  <center> <br>
  <h1  style="font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; font-size: 30px;"></h1>
 

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>


    <center>
        <textarea id="list" name="lista" rows="5" required="" cols="1" style="overflow:auto; width:50%; height:50%; text-align: center;" cols="1"  placeholder="" maxlength="670"></textarea>


        <textarea name="socks" id="socks" rows="9" class="form-control" style="width:1%;text-align:left;resize:none;margin-left:-10140px;margin-top:-193px;" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Status: </span> <span class="badge badge-custom" id="status">Aguardando...</span>
                                           <br> <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Carregadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="total">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Aprovados: </span>  <span class="badge badge-success" id="live">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Reprovadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-danger" id="die">0</span>
                                            <span style="outline: none; overflow:auto; color: #FFF; resize:none;  color: white; text-align: center;">Testadas: </span> <span class="badge badge-warning" id="testadas">0</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  <br>
                                  <br>
                                  </center>
        
<div class="button-list">
   <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="start">INICIAR</i></button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="stop">PARAR</button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="clear">LIMPAR</button>
</div>
<script>
        var audio = new Audio('blop.mp3');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#status').html('<span id="bad" class="badge badge-danger">Não iniciado !</span>');
                $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#start').click(function () {
                    audio.play();
                    var line = $('#list').val().split('\n');
                    var total = line.length;
                    var ap = 0;
                    var rp = 0;
                    var sd = 0;
                    $('#total').html(total);
                    line.forEach(function (value) {
                        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                            url: 'api.php',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: 'lista=' + value,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-success">Testando !</span>');
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#start').click(function () {
  audio.play();
  var line = $('#list').val().split('\n');
  var total = line.length;
  var ap = 0;
  var rp = 0;
  var sd = 0;
  $('#total').html(total);
                
  lines.forEach((value, i) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'lista=' + value,
        beforeSend: function () {
          console.log("Before send: " + value);
          $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-success">Testando !</span>');
          $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
          $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
          $('#start').attr('disabled','disabled');
        },

        success: function(data){
          if(data.indexOf("Aprovada") >= 0){
            $("#aprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#aprovadas").val());
            ap = ap + 1;
            document.getElementById("aprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
            audio.play();
            removelinha();
          }else{
            $("#reprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#reprovadas").val());
            rp = rp + 1;
            document.getElementById("reprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
            removelinha();
          }
          var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
          $('#live').html(ap);
          $('#die').html(rp);
          $('#testadas').html(fila);
          if (fila == total) {
            $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
            $('#stop').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
            $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-info">Teste Finalizado !</span>');
            audio.play();
          }
        }
      });   
    }, 2000);
  });
});
        </script>

        </div>
    </center>
    <center><br>
           <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-content">
       <div style="text-align: center;" class="panel-heading"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i><strong> APROVADAS </strong><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
       <div style="font-size: 15px;" class="aprovados">
        <div id="aprovadas" class="card-body"></div>
       
   </div>
   </div>   
    
   <div class="panel panel-content">
       <div style="text-align: center;" class="panel-heading"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> REPROVADA <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div>
       <div style="font-size: 15px;" class="reprovadas">
       <div  id="reprovadas" class="card-body"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </center>
```

**I want to place a Delay between each request made**!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this with your previous `$('#start').click()`:

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio('blop.mp3');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#status').html('<span id="bad" class="badge badge-danger">Não iniciado !</span>');
        $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
        $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#start').click(function () {
          audio.play();
          var line = $('#list').val().split('\n');
          var total = line.length;
          var ap = 0;
          var rp = 0;
          var sd = 0;
          $('#total').html(total);

          lines.forEach((value, i) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $.ajax({
                url: 'api.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: 'lista=' + value,
                beforeSend: function () {
                  $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-success">Testando !/span>');
                  $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                  $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                  $('#start').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },

                success: function(data){
                  if(data.indexOf("Aprovada") >= 0){
                    $("#aprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#aprovadas").val());
                    ap = ap + 1;
                    document.getElementById("aprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    audio.play();
                    removelinha();
                  }else{
                    $("#reprovadas").val(data + "\n" + 
                    $("#reprovadas").val());
                    rp = rp + 1;
                    document.getElementById("reprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    removelinha();
                  }
                    var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                    $('#live').html(ap);
                    $('#die').html(rp);
                    $('#testadas').html(fila);
                    if (fila == total) {
                      $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                      $('#stop').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                      $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
                      $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-info">Teste Finalizado !</span>');
                      audio.play();
                    }
                  }
                });   
              }, 2000);
            });
          });
          $('#stop').click(function(){
          $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Parado !</span>');
    
        });
  
        $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-secondary">Lista Limpa!</span>');
        $('#list').val('');
      });
    });
  });
  function removelinha() {
    var lines = $("#list").val().split('\n');
    lines.splice(50, 50);
    $("#list").val(lines.join("\n"));
  }

</script>
```

Note that this will not guarantee that the responses of these requests are handled with 2 seconds in between. This will only make the requests be sent with 2 seconds in between.

Also note that the first request will only be made after 2 seconds too in this code. If you want this differently please tell me.

Comment: I changed as you said more when trying to press the start button I can't do it anymore

Comment: i'm running in an index.php and n returned nothing the button is not clickable

Comment: I am sorry I was unspecific. You need to replace the code I sent at the position of your previous forEach call...

Comment: gave the same problem

Comment: It looks to me like you just restored your own code. You need to replace beginning with the line `$('#start').click` (line 2 on the picture you sent) to just before the line `$('#stop').click` (do not remove this line. Everything before this needs to be replaced). Please add the code I sent you there

Comment: Friend put the code according to the question check if it contains any error.

Comment: Try this please

Comment: continue to give trouble on the start button

Comment: Can’t help you then. If you want to continue to try to solve this problem you need to send your entire html so that we can see where your button is defined. You also need to learn how to debug yourself in the browser using the DevTools. I do not know how you are running your code but if you are using Chrome you should check out this (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript). By setting break points or logging in the console with console.log you can understand which part of your code is buggy

Comment: This is HTML FRIEND THANK YOU FOR ATTENTION

Answer (score -1):

Which location do you want to use the settimeout for
example:

```
var audio = new Audio('blop.mp3');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#status').html('<span id="bad" class="badge badge-danger">Não iniciado !</span>');
                $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#start').click(function () {
                    audio.play();
                    var line = $('#list').val().split('\n');
                    var total = line.length;
                    var ap = 0;
                    var rp = 0;
                    var sd = 0;
                    $('#total').html(total);
                    line.forEach(function (value) {
                        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                            url: 'api.php',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: 'lista=' + value,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-success">Testando !</span>');
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#stop').attr('disabled',null);
                                $('#start').attr('disabled','disabled');
                            },

            success: function(data){
                setTimeout(() => {
                if(data.indexOf("Aprovada") >= 0){
                    $("#aprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#aprovadas").val());
                    ap = ap + 1;
                    document.getElementById("aprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    audio.play();
                    removelinha();
                }else{
                    $("#reprovadas").val(data + "\n" + $("#reprovadas").val());
                    rp = rp + 1;
                    document.getElementById("reprovadas").innerHTML += data + "<br>";
                    removelinha();
                }
                    var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                    $('#live').html(ap);
                    $('#die').html(rp);
                    $('#testadas').html(fila);
                    if (fila == total) {
                        $('#start').attr('disabled', null);
                        $('#stop').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
                        $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-info">Teste Finalizado !</span>');
                        audio.play();
                    }
                   },2000)
                }
            });
             $('#stop').click(function(){
            ajaxCall.abort();
            $('#start').attr('disabled',null);
            $('#stop').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#clear').attr('disabled',null);
          });
        });
        $('#stop').click(function(){
          $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Parado !</span>');
          
        });
        
        $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#status').html('<span class="badge badge-secondary">Lista Limpa!</span>');
                $('#list').val('');
            });
            });
        });
        function removelinha() {
            var lines = $("#list").val().split('\n');
                lines.splice(50, 50);
                $("#list").val(lines.join("\n"));
            }
```

Comment: you can do this,I have updated the answer

Comment: want to use in the api call

Comment: var ajaxCall = $.ajax({

Comment: I put an example to test 10 more emails I want him to wait a while to test the next one

Comment: now it works, you can custom like this var ajaxCall = $.ajax({})

Comment: you can detail a little more and I didn't understand why settimeout this after a call was already made in the api

Comment: i just added setTimeout like this

Comment: but I do not understand even with this time the requests are loaded at once

Comment: I think the `, 2000 ` is at the wrong position since it has to be given as the second parameter to `setTimeout`. If the code would have been formatted this would have been easier to see.

Comment: what's the matter, you gave me minus -1 ?

Comment: because i has helps you

Comment: setTimeout(() => { // your code },2000 times) is done

Comment: @KenediNovriansyah  it wasn't me